# JPA SqlResultSetMapping object order

Tags: jpa, sqlresultsetmapping

JPA: if classes, entities and columns are defined in @SqlResultSetMapping, what is the order of objects returned?

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
       name="CustomerDetailsResult",
       classes={
          @ConstructorResult(
               targetClass=com.example.Customer.class,
                 columns={
                    @ColumnResult(name="id"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="name"),
                 }
          )
       },
       entities={ 
            @EntityResult(entityClass=com.example.Order.class, fields={
                @FieldResult(name="id", column="order_id"),
                @FieldResult(name="quantity", column="order_quantity"), 
                @FieldResult(name="item", column="order_item")})},
        columns={
            @ColumnResult(name="item_name")}
      )
```

The result row is Object[]{customer, order, scalar_value}, or Object[]{order, scalar_value, customer}, etc.

Comment: Do you mean the order of the columns in the row or the order of the rows in the List after calling getResultList() on the query?

Comment: the order of objects in a row.

Answer (score 0):

The result will contain the object as you defined it in the @SqlResultSetMapping.

In your case:

```
Object[]{customer, order, scalar_value}
```